# Another triple.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Solving the equation. $X^2+Y^2+Z^2=X^3$

got some solutions, but still the question remains. Below are all the decisions or not?

$X=5t^2+2t+2$

$Y=11t^3+5t^2+2t$

$Z=2t^3+10t^2+4t+2$

And more.

$X=2a^2(a-1)^2b^4-2a(a-1)b^3+(2a^2-2a+1)b^2+1$

$Y=2a^3(a-1)^3b^6+2a^2(a-1)^2(a-3)b^5+3a(a-1)b^4+a(4a^2-8a+3)b^3-$$-(a-1)(a+2)b^2+ab$

$Z=2a^3(a-1)^3b^6-2a^3(a-1)^2b^5+a(a-1)(4a^2-3)b^4-(a-1)(4a+1)b^3+$$+a(a+1)b^2+(a-1)b$

Comment: Your expression for $Y$ has two $t^2$ terms.

Comment: $X=Y=Z=3$ is an obvious solution not captured by the first set. Are you solving for integers?

Comment: Yes. There's a typo. Already corrected.

Comment: I certainly did not consider the trivial solution. They poluchayutsya replacement $Y=aX$ and $Z=bX$. Then: $X=a^2+b^2+1$ and $Y=a^3+ab^2+a$ and $Z=ba^2+b^3+b$